# Convert oga (Telegram audio file fpormat) to ogg/wav file format using Python

Tags: python, wav, ogg

Not able to proceed ahead.
We get .oga file from record in Telegram app.
Which needs to be converted to wav/ogg file format for further processing.

Comment: You can use FFMPEG to convert audios https://www.ffmpeg.org/

Answer (score 0):

Taking in consideration, that this answer is purely academic, I had not try it. You can use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org), and run it through python with `subprocess`.

```
import subprocess
src_filename = 'source.ext1'
dest_filename = 'output.ext2'

process = subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', src_filename, dest_filename])
```

NOTE: *Looking around, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852175/how-to-convert-telegram-voice-in-a-wave-file-in-python) that may be the same that you asked.*

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]
Does the output file need to exist?