# pyTelegramBotAPI and SpeechRecognition

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, wav, ogg, py-telegram-bot-api

I am building a Telegram bot using pyTelegramBotAPI. The bot is supposed to get a voice message from a user and perform text recognition using SpeechRecognition library. As I know telegram voice messages are ogg files and speechrecognition does not support ogg, hence I need to convert it either to wav or to flac (or any other format that is supported by SpeechRecognition). I am doing it as suggested here [How to convert Telegram voice in a wave file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852175/how-to-convert-telegram-voice-in-a-wave-file-in-python?answertab=active#tab-top)

However the following code...

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice', 'audio'])
def get_audio_messages(message):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.voice.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    with open('user_voice.ogg', 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    src_filename = 'user_voice.ogg'
    dest_filename = 'user_voice_output.flac'

    process = subprocess.run(['C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe', '-i', src_filename, dest_filename])
    if process.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception("Something went wrong")

    with open('user_voice_output.flac', 'rb') as user_audio:
        text = r.recognize_google(user_audio)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text)
```

... still yields the following error:

```
line 822, in recognize_google assert isinstance(audio_data, AudioData), "``audio_data`` must be audio data" 
    AssertionError: ``audio_data`` must be audio data
```

Am I missing something about ogg to flac or ogg to wav conversion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Telegram voice in a wave file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852175/how-to-convert-telegram-voice-in-a-wave-file-in-python)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you, I managed to convert it to wav, hovewer I still get * audio_data must be audio data* error when I feed the wav file to the SpeechRecognizer. The same happens if I convert the voice message to flac instead of wav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_17718/slides/chapter2.pdf

```
import speech_recognition as sr    
user_audio_file = sr.AudioFile("user_voice_output.wav")
with user_audio_file as source:
    user_audio = r.record(source)
text = r.recognize_google(user_audio, language='en-US')
```